# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest after adding Nimble in SPM

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a workspace that has a 3 different projects. My dependencies look like this:

```
- App 1
- App 2
- Shared libraries
```

After adding Nimble to my shared library project, it compiles, but I always get a crash saying:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest
```

I checked my Search Path Frameworks and Other Linked Flags of my apps, but  there's no XCTest, and I don't want XCTest to be in there. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I added Nimble as a dependency in my shared library. I meant to put it in the testing target, but accidentally put it in the main target.

When I go to Project > Swift Packages and see Nimble, it does not specify which target my package belongs in, which spurred the confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I had to remove my dependency (in my case Cuckoo) and add it again to select the correct target